# How to randomize the order of values in a column in R, but keep specific balance of unique values?

Tags: r

I would really appreciate some help with this! I want to create a data table with 4 columns:

```
ROUTE SCENE REPEAT CONTEXT
  A    1     1      YES
  A    2     1      NO
  A    3     1      NO
```

There are 6 routes (A-F) and 10 scenes per route (1-10). Each route needs to be repeated 10 times, so the REPEAT column will have values 1-10 like this:

```
ROUTE SCENE REPEAT CONTEXT
  A    1     1      YES
  A    2     1      NO
  A    3     1      NO
  .
  .
  B    1     1      NO
  B    2     1      YES
  .
  .
  A    1     2      NO
  A    2     2      YES
  A    3     2      YES
```

And there will be 600 rows in total in the data table.

I am struggling with getting the CONTEXT column right. For each route (A-F), 5 rows of the CONTEXT column must have value YES and 5 must have value NO, but in random order. Also, across all 10 iterations of each route A-F, each unique scene must appear 5 times with CONTEXT = YES and 5 times with CONTEXT = NO. So for instance:

```
ROUTE SCENE REPEAT CONTEXT
  A    1     1      YES
  .
  A    1     2      NO
  .
  A    1     3      YES
  .    
  A    1     4      NO 
  .
  .
  A    1     10     NO
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
library(data.table)

randomiser <- function(i,j){

     context_combo <- rep(c('YES','NO'), 5)

     set <- data.table(
     ROUTE = i,
     SCENE = seq(1:10),
     REPEAT = j,
     CONTEXT = sample(context_combo, size = 10, replace = FALSE))


     return(set)

}

i = rep(rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), each = 10), 10)
j = rep(c(1:10), each = 60)

newDT <- randomiser(i,j)
```

However, this gives me the same "YES/NO" sequence for CONTEXT for each value of ROUTE and for each value of REPEAT throughout the data table. I am not sure how to change the code so that the YES/NO order for each route is random, and so that for each scene across all 10 iterations of each route, there are 5 cases of CONTEXT = YES and 5 cases of CONTEXT = NO.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to create a context column with YES and NO which are randomly sampled 5 times each. You can do:

```
# sample data
df <- data.table(route = rep(LETTERS[1:6], each=10), scene = rep(1:10, 6))

# result
df[,context := sample(rep(c('YES','NO'), each=5)),.(route)]

head(df, 10)

    route scene context
 1:     A     1      NO
 2:     A     2      NO
 3:     A     3     YES
 4:     A     4      NO
 5:     A     5     YES
 6:     A     6     YES
 7:     A     7     YES
 8:     A     8      NO
 9:     A     9      NO
10:     A    10     YES
11:     B     1     YES
12:     B     2     YES
13:     B     3     YES
14:     B     4      NO
15:     B     5      NO
```